# sort list of dictionaries based on "sub-string" present within dict's value string

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in python, called `all_data`. The structure of each `dict` object hold by `all_data` is:

```
{
    'href': u'http://malc0de.com/database/index.php?search=c.img001.com', 
    'type': u'text/html', 
    'rel': u'alternate',
    'title': u'c.img001.com', 
    'summary': u'URL: c.img001.com/re58/girlshow_20300025849.exe, IP Address: 14.215.74.85, Country: CN, ASN: 58543, MD5: 31d5f481153ccd2829558720f8d90d81', 
    'title_detail': {
        'base': u'http://malc0de.com/rss/', 
        'type': u'text/plain', 
        'value': u'c.img001.com', 
        'language': None
     }
}
```

I want to perform sorting base on the name of `'Country'` which is present as sub-string to the value of `'summary'` key. The content of string is like:

```
u'URL: c.img001.com/re58/girlshow_20300025849.exe, IP Address: 14.215.74.85, Country: CN, ASN: 58543, MD5: 31d5f481153ccd2829558720f8d90d81',
```

I want to sort the `list` of `dict`s based on the `Country` name in the alphabetical order.

Comment: Why has this question got so many downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value `'Country'` on which you want to sort is present as the part of string in the key `'summary'`; you have to firstly extract the value of `'Country'` in order to perform the sorting.

One way is to create the function to convert the `str` to `dict` as:

```
def get_dict_from_str(my_str):
    return dict(item.split(': ') for item in my_str.split(', '))
```

Then use this function along with *lambda function* with `sorted()` as:

```
sorted_list = sorted(dict_list, key=lambda x: get_dict_from_str(x['summary'])['Country'])
```

where `dict_list` is list of dictionaries holding the dicts of format as is mentioned in the question.